# mac os freeze but no logs in the console messages

Tags: macos, google-chrome, freeze, crash

My max os keeps crashing about once a day, I've noted down the exact time (down to the second) and checked in the console messages. But got no messages at all for that entire ten minutes.

It crashed when I was opening a new tab on chrome for watching a video from a tv streamer.

Other times it crashes while I'm doing something else. It's pretty annoying and I'm not sure how to figure out what's the problem with the computer.

The computer just freezes, the mouse arrow stops moving, the watch freezes and seconds don't move anymore, and the only thing I'm able to do is to press the power button until the computer shuts, and then restart it.

When I restart my computer restarts normally as nothing happened.

How can I investigate what causes the crashes?

here's the description of my pc:

[image]

Comment: If this is just happening from Chrome - reinstall it and do not install any add-ons or plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to popular belief, macs are not immune to viruses. If you said you were watching a video from a TV streamer, then that might be the problem. Don't watch the video, and see if it works then. If not, try rebooting, then try [rebooting from safe mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1564), then try [resetting the NVRAM and PRAM by holding command option p and r](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379), and if that fails, then I would recommend backing up important files, and restoring your computer to when the problem didn't occur, or simply backing up and reinstalling your operating system by booting from OSX Recovery (www.apple.com/osx/recovery/)